# How to generate specific action URL when I have multiple route attributes?

Tags: c#, .net, model-view-controller, asp.net-core, routes

In my application I have a base controller class which defines two routes:

```
// OPControllerBase.cs
[ApiController]
[Route("/[controller]", Order = 1)]
[Route("/inline/[controller]", Order = 2)]
public abstract class OPControllerBase : Controller
{
}
```

All my derived controllers can be accessed via /[controller] or by /inline/[controller]. The individual actions are decorated with HttpGet/Post and may provide additional route segment representing the action.
Here is a derived controller example:

```
public class ProductController : OPControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet("Edit/{code}")]
    public IActionResult Edit(string code)
    {
       // accessible via both:
       // /Product/Edit/CODE
       // /inline/Product/Edit/CODE
    }
}
```

Inside my _ViewStart.cshtml I basically decide on the layout depending through which route the controller was invoked:

```
// _ViewStart.cshtml
@{
    var path = ViewContext.HttpContext.Request.Path.Value;
    if(path.StartsWith("/inline/"))
    {
        Layout = "_InlineLayout";
    }
    else
    {
        Layout = "_FullLayout";
    }
}
```

The problem I have is that inside my view I would need to generate a route depending on how the controller was invoked. If the controller was invoked via '/inline/[controller]' route I would then like to generate Urls which start with '/inline/. In addition I would also like to choose which route to generate in certain scenarios.

Currently whenever I generate Url it always uses the first route. 
How can I force it to use the second?

**Edit:** 
Just to clarify when I say 'generate' URL I mean using Url.Action or similar method. Of course I can always explicitly write the url:

```
var productCode = "TEST";
var fullRoute = "/Product/Edit/" + productCode 
var inlineRoute = "/inline/Product/Edit/" + productCode
```

... but this is not what I would like to do. What I would like to have is something like (just an example which does not work of course):

```
var productCode = "TEST";
var fullRoute = Url.Action("Edit", "Product", new { code=productCode , inline = false})
var inlineRoute = Url.Action("Edit", "Product", new { code=productCode , inline = true})
```

Comment: Why don't you just inject an service interface to your controller and write the functions in that? By so, you can get a enum value in the query to your related controller endpoint and then you will be able to call and handle different types of request as you wish.

Comment: @Hasan I do not understand what do you mean. Which functions?. My routing works just fine, the question is how to generate a controller/action Url if I have two possible routes such as I've stated in my example (if I want to generate routes via Url.Action or similar).

Answer (score 0):

This feels like your `inline` variable needs to be just that: a proper variable, passed in so that you can read the value.  Yes, that complicates the method declaration, but it also clearly indicates to anybody maintaining things later that you're using it for something in particular.  It also feels like an awful lot of gymnastics just to get the layout set, so maybe there's some refactoring to be done so you're not going down this path?

OK, editing to throw out a "for instance" for what I'm thinking here:

`[Route("/{inline:bool=yes}/[controller]")]`

I'm probably getting that syntax wrong for the variable declaration (not sure I can assign a default in this context, etc.), but worth a try?

You're going to run into trouble with this, though, in that the route may be undifferentiable from other routes containing an initial `bool` parameter, so I'd be inclined to move that later in the route, possibly as the final (optional) parameter.

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by 'variable'. Can you please provide an example of such a system. Also how does such a 'variable' help generate a correct url when using method such as Url.Action or similar?

Comment: I revised my answer a bit.  Not sure if it'll work, but worth a shot?